# Is Azure WebDeploy safe for production Web Apps?

Tags: deployment, continuous-deployment, azure, appveyor

We use Azure [Web Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/web/) in production. We deploy using [WebDeploy](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/web/) either by right-clicking the project in Visual Studio and choosing "Publish..." or via CI in AppVeyor, which is WebDeploy ready.

My question is: **Is WebDeploy safe for production environments?** Will it interrupt running processes, or does it work some magic to make sure it doesn't? Can we publish to production using WebDeploy during business hours (when our customers are active) and not worry about it? A good answer will provide some documentation on this, as I have not been able to find this yet.

Answer (score 1):

WebDeploy by itself cannot guarantee if your application pool will not be recycled during deployment. To be on the safe side, I would use [deployment slots](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/videos/azure-websites-deployment-slots-for-staging-sites/). 
Also I would recommend to tag question with `azure-web-sites` so right people will help you.

Comment: We have deployment slots that we deploy to using WebDeploy. We do not use the swapping feature because we want our git branches to be controlling of what is in each slot - git pushing to develop, release-candidate, or master causes our CI server to do a publish to that deployment slot on a successful build. Are you saying that the swapping feature is safe? The tag azure-web-sites does not exist nor do I have enough rep to create it.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using web deploy for ages and it’s been very stable except for couple of azure outage times.

Suggest using [deployment slots](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-staged-publishing). You can use a CD like [visual studio team services](https://www.visualstudio.com/vso/) and first web deploy to the slot and add a step to swap the ‘staging’ slot with ‘production’.

If you are using a basic deploy approach you can turn on auto swap which triggers upon successful deployment to the ‘staging’ slot. I personally don’t like this and have seen issues with this.